# Is Jonas Quinn typical of his species?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In Season 5 of *Stargate: SG-1*, team member Daniel Jackson was briefly replaced by Jonas Quinn, a human from Langara. In addition to an optimistic, almost child-like curiosity about everything, Quinn shows numerous intellectual abilities above and beyond the average human. He can read quickly, remembers everything he reads or watches on TV (photographic memory?), and is even able to learn new languages abnormally fast. He often shrugs off his abilities, simply calling himself "a quick study".

Unfortunately, we never see much of Quinn's planet or nation, with other Langarans only appearing in a couple of episodes. Quinn eventually leaves SG-1 to return there, joining the new ruling council on his planet and hoping to unite his people. However, we never really hear any more about Quinn or the Langaran people after that.

**Is Jonas Quinn typical of humans on Langara, or is he unique even there?**

Answer (score 2):

He does go away to serve in the armed forces of a *foreign power* (Earth or the United States, depening on how the Langaran count it). Then he comes back to take a key position in his government.

- Breaking the fourth wall, this could be an example of [being put on a bus](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PutOnABus). And also of [the main characters do everything](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheMainCharactersDoEverything).
- Alternatively, he was exceptional enough *for a Kelownan* (subset of all Langarans) to earn a slot on the ruling council.
- Or he was actually a military operative under orders to serve in Earth's forces against the common enemy. A bit like the [Flying Tigers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Tigers) or ['Chinese' Gordon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_George_Gordon). A bit surprising if he managed to fool SGC all the time ...
- On this council, he supervised a research project. (Huh? Granted, it turned out to be an important project.) Well, maybe his alien travel experience really did count for getting that job.

But note that it took Samantha Carter to recognize that Kianna Cyr's tunneling vehicle was out of the ordinary. Seems that the **Langarans** saw nothing wrong when a young woman invented such a gadget. Erratic geniuses might be more common on Langara than on Earth.